# Issue loading context from ClassPathXmlApplicationContext

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-integration

I am learning spring integration from a collection of github examples. I was having difficulty getting the maven-based dependencies to integrate with my eclipse, so I simply created a corresponding project from scratch and imported all the required spring jars, etc.

Anyway, I have a basic HelloWorld project from the github that I am getting an error at runtime. The error is

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [META-INF/helloWorldDemo.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

,which I suspect is due to the manual structuring of my java project. I would attach the project, but don't believe I can do that from stackoverflow (unless I am mistaken?). So instead, I am hoping the attached image could shed light on the solution. I assume my problem has something to do with line 29 of HelloWorldApp.javacode not recognizing that the helloWordDemo.xml is in the ~WebContent/META-INF location, but not sure how to address. grateful for any ideas. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: try to remove the meta-inf and add that file in the folder which contains your java class

Comment: thank you. I tried that, and got further, but then got a new error:Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration]
Offending resource: class path resource [base/helloWorldDemo.xml]. The xml file references several namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Your META-INF resides inside another folder `WebContent`. Add it to the path:

```
appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:/WebContent/META-
INF/helloWorldDemo.xml");
```

Comment: Ivan Pronin, thanks for response. I tried your suggestion, but I am getting the same error. Did you mean literally the way you specified above? that did not work. thanks again.